# How to get the sum of two fields in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
const ledgerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
debitValue: Number,
creditValue: Number,
debitAccount: [],
creditAccount: [],
date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
journal_id: String
});
```

I want to sum all values in "debitValue" and "creditValue" within a certain timeline (for example from beginning to end of year).
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you explain how the expected output would look like?

Comment: This collection is for a single account, let say it's for "cash" , for every transaction I create new record in the cash collection and put a value in either "debitValue" or "creditValue". and I want to know the sum in both fields during a certain time frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use aggregation and get the sum using the [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#std-label-sum-project-example) operator, and I assume u need sum of debit and credit separately and not together.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { '$match':{ "date":{$gt:startDate,$lt:endDate}}},
   {
    '$group':{ _id:"_id","debitScore":{$sum:"$debitValue"}, "creditScore":{$sum:"$creditValue"}}
   }
])
```